# Apple Mach-O framework error

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, linker

I'm trying to install the DevMate framework. I've followed every step on [DevMates website](http://docs.devmate.com/v1.0/docs/integrate-devmate-kit), and i cant compile my app. I've added it into the link binary with libraries tab, and the copy files build phase tab. Everything is where it should be but I'm still getting this error:

> ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Users/Saturn/Documents/Floating Lunch Box/Xcode/StatScreen/Users/Saturn/Documents/Floating Lunch Box/Xcode/StatScreen/StatScreen/DevMateKit/DevMateKit.framework/Frameworks'
>   ld: file not found: @rpath/DevMateIssuesReporter.framework/Versions/A/DevMateIssuesReporter for architecture x86_64
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use iv to see invocation)`

I'm sorry if this is some stupid fix but I'm new to programming and I just want to implement this framework without having so much trouble. Thanks for any help!

Xcode 6.4
Cocoa Apphttp://docs.devmate.com/v1.0/docs/integrate-devmate-kit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem described here is that linker could not find directory `/Users/Saturn/Documents/Floating Lunch Box/Xcode/StatScreen/Users/Saturn/Documents/Floating Lunch Box/Xcode/StatScreen/StatScreen/DevMateKit/DevMateKit.framework/Frameworks` where `DevMateIssuesReporter.frameworks` should be.

Are you sure this is the correct path to DevMateKit.framework? I think it should be `/Users/Saturn/Documents/Floating Lunch Box/Xcode/StatScreen/StatScreen/DevMateKit/DevMateKit.framework/Frameworks`. Try to correct it. You can also use Examples project at [GitHub](https://github.com/DevMate/DevMateKit).

Answer (score 2):

This was bugging me a lot lately. DevMakeKit contains a nested DevMateIssuesReporter framework and Xcode cannot find it without its path specified in `FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS`, that's kind of what Dmytro says.

But you can also tell Xcode to perform recursive search inside the specified framework path, by selecting `recursive` option in the popover dialogue.

[image]

The gotcha is to ensure `EXCLUDED_RECURSIVE_SEARCH_PATH_SUBDIRECTORIES` doesn't contain `*.framework` entry, otherwise Xcode ignores `DevMateKit.framework/Frameworks`. It seems you can do the same using `INCLUDED_RECURSIVE_SEARCH_PATH_SUBDIRECTORIES`, but I didn't have much success with that.